# How to change(add) app engine sdk eclipse plugin 1.7 to 1.6?

Tags: google-app-engine

I install eclipse 3.7 and app engine plug-in 3.7..

Google app engine deploy needs java 1.6 .. 
(Java7 code causes of deploy Error  T_T)

How can I change/add appengine-java-sdk-1.7.4 to appengine-java-sdk-1.6.4?

Eclipse plugin(http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7) has only sdk 1.7.4
and google sdk download link(https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads) has only 1.7.4 T_T

thanks...

Comment: I misunderstand java version/ app engine version.. if os/eclipse jdk/jre version is java 1.6, appengine-java-sdk-1.7.4 is no matter to deploy app engine(no deploy error)...In summary, app-engine-java-sdk version do not give a influence to java7 error. :)

Comment: how did u solve this? i have java 1.6, and i cannot use 1.7. what do i do with the appengine plugin?